# Update Columns With Array (Mysql Procedure)

Tags: mysql, arrays, sql-update, procedure, where-in

I have array like this

```
text_id_array=["1011", "1012", "1013"]
```

I want to pass it to mysql procedure for update columns where it matches with array members so i tried

```
BEGIN
UPDATE chat_texts a SET a.read_by=a.read_by+1 WHERE a.text_id IN (text_id_array); 
END
```

but it only works on first member of array **1011**. I know there is a lot of question like that but i couldn't find the solution. Thanks for helps!

Comment: Why are you doing this entirely within MySQL ? It just seems unlikely that someone would manually pass an array to a database.

Comment: Because i am sending some text_ids to convert  their **read_by** values +1 in DB. I can do it with php loop but i thought send all these ids in one array and done rest operations with mysql procedure will give me a better performance.

Comment: I see. I suspect the PHP solution will be faster. Remember to *build* the query inside the loop, but *execute* the query outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i found it. Thanks for recommend to use **FIND_IN_SET** but also i have noticed that i should change my param to **VARCHAR**. So there it is

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `aa`(IN `text_array_id` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
UPDATE chat_texts a SET a.read_by=a.read_by+1 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(a.text_id, text_array_id);
END
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in having a non-array approach, [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set%20) might help.

This might help you get started:

```
SET @strIDs ="1011,1012,1013"
UPDATE chat_texts a SET a.read_by=a.read_by+1 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(a.text_id, @strIDs);
```

Comment: doesn't work. still getting same issue. i think main problem is passing array to procedure because when i use `UPDATE chat_texts a SET a.read_by=a.read_by+1 WHERE a.text_id IN ('1010','1011')` it works as expected but when i call procedure it is taking param like **('1010,1011')**